# Switching view between view controllers

Tags: objective-c

I am currently working on the login function using Objective-C. I've created 2 view controller such as the default one which is my login page (viewcontroller) and my homepage (homepageVC). But after the user is authenticated. The view doesn't switch from login page to home page.

Here is my code view switching code:

```
NSLog(@"Login SUCCESS");
[self alertStatus:@"Logged in Successfully." :@"Login Success!"];
//redirect to homepage
homepageVC *controller = [self.storyboard   instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"homepage"];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:controller animated:YES];
```

Comment: Make sure `self` here is in the stack of a `UINavigationController`, if not `self.navigationController` is nil.

Comment: Sorry for asking such question, can i know how do i check whether my `self` is in the stack of `UINavigationController` or not. I'm a beginner. @kudocc

Comment: In the stack of `UINavigationController` means `self` is the root of a `UINavigationController` (`initWithRootViewController:` method of `UINavigationController`) or `self` is pushed into the stack (`pushViewController:animated:`).

Comment: are you sure identifier is correct ? `homepage`

Comment: @Cade Thank you for your advice, I've insert the wrong identifier, and my problem is fix now !